# Selecting choices of checkBoxGroup based on created data

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I am working on a Shiny App where I created some data in different places and I would like to use a checkBoxGroup to list the data that are already created or not.

So let imagine there are 3 data and 2 are already created, these two should have the tick on and empty the one which is still null. Here below my guess which is not working.

Thanks in advance

```
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    checkboxGroupInput("inCheckboxGroup", "Input checkbox",c("data A", "data B", "data C"))
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    data_A <- NULL
    data_B <- 1
    data_C <- 3

    observe({
      a <- data_A
      b <- data_B
      c <- data_C

      selectedBox <- which(!c(is.null(a),is.null(b),is.null(c)))
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "inCheckboxGroup2",
                               choices = c("Data A", "Data B", "Data C"),
                               selected = selectedBox
      )
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not far off! This works for me

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("inCheckboxGroup", "Input checkbox",c("data A", "data B", "data C")),
  textOutput("showData"),
  useShinyjs()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  loadData <- reactive({
    runjs("Shiny.onInputChange('dataLoaded',true)")
    list(
      data_A = NULL,
      data_B = 1,
      data_C = 3
    )
  })

  observeEvent({input$dataLoaded},{

    selectedBox <- which(!sapply(loadData(),is.null))
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "inCheckboxGroup",
                             choices = c("Data A", "Data B", "Data C"),
                             selected = c("Data A", "Data B", "Data C")[selectedBox]
    )
  })
  output$showData <- renderText(
    paste(sapply(loadData(),print),collapse = "\n")
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

hope it helps!

Comment: This helps a bit (I wouldn't ever have thought of this solution) as it works in this example. But in the App where data are created after loading or dynamically, it doesn't. The issue is on the observe object. It passes only the first time when the app starts up and not later.

Comment: @Stefano I made an update using *shinyjs* so that once the data is loaded it fires an input-event which then triggers the observer. Maybe you can do something similar in your code

Comment: it is (in a less elegant way) what I was trying to do to overcome the problem. I'll follow your suggestion, thanks a lot!